# Request Segment URL

Tags: segments, getsegment

I'm trying to declare if a user is on a /uk or /us version of the site.

domain.com/uk/
domain.com/us/

```
{% if (craft.app.request.segments == '/uk/') %}
UK site
{% endif %}
```

This doesnt work. Can anyone explain why and where I'm going wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The request segments will come back as an array, where each part between slashes will be an array element so `mysite.com/first/second/third` gives segments `[first,second,third]`

If you're just looking for the first segment, you can try
`(craft.app.request.segments|first == 'uk')`
to get that information.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Comment: That should work. With ``devMode`` on, when you do a ``{{ dump(craft.app.request.segments) }}`` what are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Craft's [multi-site functionality](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/sites.html)(?), you'll want to use something like `{{ currentSite.handle }}` to check which site they're on. For multiple sites configured to use sub-directories from a single domain name, the first segment of the URL is considered to be part of the `siteUrl` and will not be returned in the segments array.